# How to logout from tty without killing xorg

Tags: bspwm

I'm currently using bspwm as my window manager, it launches automatically thanks to my `.zprofile` & `.xinitrc`

How can i go back to the tty login without running `bspc quit`

I know that i can change to another tty using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F {1,10}</kbd>

But since i'm not using any display/login manager, i would like to use tty as my "block screen" so whenever i enter my user password all my windows still open.

Comment: You can't. Just use a screen locker (e.g. i3-lock).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using `tmux` or `screen`.

I'm not sure if these satisfy your requirements exactly, but you can easily 'detach' them and they will continue running when you log out. When you log in again you simply 'attach' to the running session again and the previously started applications will still be there.

Comment: do you've any resource on this?